# How to append/merge a list of dictionaries with another list of dictionary having only different keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionaries and I want to do something like this:

```
list1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}]
list2 = [{"a": 1}, {"d": 4}, {"e": 5}}
```

`expected_output`

```
list1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}, {"d": 4}, {"e": 5}]
```

So here, in list2, as dictionary {"a": 1} is a subset of dictionary in list 1 so we don't add that but we add the ones not in list1.

How can I achieve this above expected output?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where is it failing

Answer (score 0):

```
l1_keys = list1[0].keys()

for item in list2:
    for key in item:
        if key not in l1_keys:
            list1.append({key:item[key]})
```

Answer (score 0):

use list(dict.keys())[0] to get a single key to check

```
list1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}]
list2 = [{"a": 1}, {"d": 4}, {"e": 5}]
extendList = [someDict for someDict in list2 if list(someDict.keys())[0] not in list(list1[0].keys())]
list1.extend(extendList)
print(list1)

[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'d': 4}, {'e': 5}]
```